# Ruby and if statements

Tags: ruby, operators

Let me preface this with saying that I am new to Ruby.

I was trying to do something like this:

```
raise NoSuchStrategyError unless ((player1[1].downcase && player2[1].downcase) == ( "p" || "r" || "s"))
```

However it was not working as intended. It only recognized if the first argument was a "p". If it was an "r" or an "s" it threw the error. I had to write it out the long way like this for it to work:

```
raise NoSuchStrategyError unless player1[1].downcase == "p" or player1[1].downcase == "s" or player1[1].downcase == "r"
raise NoSuchStrategyError unless player2[1].downcase == "p" or player2[1].downcase == "s" or player2[1].downcase == "r"
```

Is there a better way to do this shorthand?

Comment: In Python you do `if foo in ['a', 'b', 'c']`. I'd be interested to know if Ruby can do this as well.

Comment: @Blender Indeed there is, but only the inverse via [`Enumerable#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F): `['a', 'b', 'c'].include? foo`. (Though strictly speaking [`Array` overrides `include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F).)

Comment: I realize I am a bit late, but I do not think I can keep up at the full pace of the class with my other responsibilities. I am trying to work through it as I get time

Comment: @Calihan For future homework questions be sure to tag them with the "homework" tag. Also, since you're new to SO, please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/158402) the answer that best answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `||` returns the first argument to it that is truthy. In this case, since `"p"` is truthy, `("p" || "r" || "s")` *always* returns `"p"`. Knowing this, your first statement can be equivalently rewritten as:

```
raise NoSuchStrategyError unless ((player1[1].downcase && player2[1].downcase) == "p"
```

As Blender hinted at in his comment about Python, you can do:

```
raise NoSuchStrategyError unless ['p', 'r', 'y'].include?(player1[1].downcase) && ['p', 'r', 'y'].include?(player2[1].downcase)
```

or more concisely:

```
raise NoSuchStrategyError unless [player1[1].downcase, player2[1].downcase].all? { |c| %w[p r s].include? c }
```

Additionally, be careful when using `and` & `or` in Ruby, they are different than `&&` & `||`. You can (and should) [read more about the difference](http://www.rubyinside.com/and-or-ruby-3631.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could just do:

```
"pry".include?(player1[1].downcase)
```

The real problem with your code is how you're structuring it.  When you find yourself declaring variables like player1, and player2, then writing a bunch of repetitive code to work with those variables, its usually a clue that you need to declare a "Player" class:

```
 class Player

   def initialize(name)
     @name = name
     @strategy = "goofy"
   end

   def valid_strategy?
     return "pry".include?(@strategy)
   end

 end
```

Then your line looks like this:

```
raise NoSuchStrategyError unless @player.valid_strategy?
```

Comment: or even shorter, `"pry"[player1[1].downcase]`

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it like this:

```
raise NoSuchStrategyError unless (%w(a b c).include?(player1[1].downcase) && %w(a b c).include?(player2[1].downcase))
```

**Edit**

An even simpler solution:

```
raise NoSuchStrategyError if ("pry"[player1[1].downcase] || "pry"[player2[1].downcase])
```

Comment: I think, though, despite `"pry"[player1[1].downcase]` being wonderfully brief, some of the intention of what is being done is lost in using `"pry"` as a substitute for a set of single characters.

Answer (score 1):

In your approach `('p' || 'r' || 's')` always returns 'p', since in Ruby except `nil` and `false` everything is `true` including 0. Therefore, except 'p', your approach fails.

---

Try `Array#include?` method instead.

```
plays = ['p', 'r', 's']

raise NoSuchStrategyError unless ( plays.include?(player1[1].downcase) && 
                                   plays.include?(player2[1].downcase) 
                                 )
```